# Luggage on changed booking

Tags: luggage

I booked 2 seats to fly out and back to Stockholm with one piece of hold baggage  between us.  I have changed one person to come back later.  How can I clarify that I want the hold luggage to be on the later return flight?

Comment: the airlines that I am familiar with assign the bag to a specific persons ticket, if you have an online account you should be able to check and even swap this for some airlines (easyjet, ryanair etc), others that do not allow this can be changed via phone call or even social media messages

Answer (score 1):

You call the airline or travel agent, they are the only ones capable of ensuring this.